How does auditwheel determine minimum manylinux version
I upgraded the build of my C++ based Python application to use a manylinux_2_28 docker image.  When I do auditwheel repair I notice that each wheel is using 2 different manylinux tags.
mypackage1-2.8.2-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_27_aarch64.manylinux_2_28_aarch64.whl
mypackage2-1.2.9-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_24_aarch64.manylinux_2_28_aarch64.whl

Does this mean that someone would be able to download my packages for a version of Linux with an version of glibc earlier than 2.28?  Is there any way to prevent this, as I am not sure my application will run on an earlier system?
